# gpedit.msc - export settings to a file

Tags: windows, export, group-policy

I have a big problem and I can't find a solution:
I need to export settings (changes, whatever) from **gpedit.msc**
Does someone know any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in cmd with administrator rights:

```
secedit /export /cfg group-policy.inf /log export.log
```

Comment: I thought, secedit exports the configuration done in secpol.msc, not the configuration done in gpedit.msc.